# How to train a tensorflow network using JNI on Android?

Tags: android, neural-network, tensorflow

Tensorflow is designed to compatible with mobile devices, and [there is an example of android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) using tensorflow. But I couldn't find any neural-network related functions in the source code. 
And in [tensorflow C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/cc/index.html), I couldn't find any APIs for training a network?

Is that I was too careless to find them or there is some other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android is not meant to be the training framework for Tensorflow.
Currently in the published (one and only "inception") demo you can only
use it for inference.

If you insist to train on this Arm based device you will have to compile TF for android with all the training ops & kernels that usually omitted in the process of optimizing the model for inference (for mobile), and also to write JNI interfaces for training c++ api.

A better approach is to use what is called "TF serving" and do the training on cloud with RPC. You can collect the data on your mobile and then send it for training or fine tuning a pre-trained model and then get the fine tune model back to your phone. see this demo:
[Tensorflow Cloud Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZnl6S2Q1nU)